# Should I create a method or variable for the table given below

Tags: java, queue

```
I have an assignment which says that I need to create an queue class with instruction messages on it.
and instruction message is formed of following properties

 -----------
>InstructionType integer  
> ProductCode    integer  
> Quantity       integer  
> UOM byte

--------------------------------

Can I declare all the above given properties as variables and then pass it as a parameter in a function created for instruction message and place it in the instruction queue class. Can anyone give me a sample code for proceeding with this..and let me know if I think right or any other methodologies. Can be done? please help.
```

Can anyone suggest ,If am right.Can i use like this:
    public class instructionqueue
    {
    LinkedList queue = new LinkedList()
    /* how to add,retreive and delete the instructionmessage from the queue class*/
    }
     where insturctionmessage is a class

```
public class Instructionmessage 
{

   public int Instructiontype;
   public Integer   Productcode;
   public Integer quantity;
   public byte[] UOM = new byte[256];
   public Integer Timestamp;

  /*method to set and get the instruction type  for the messages*/

   public int getInstructiontype()
   {
       return Instructiontype;
   }
   public void setInstructiontype(int newInstructtype)
   {
       Instructiontype = newInstructtype;
   }

    /*method to set and get the product code   for the messages*/

   public int getProductcode()
   {
       return Productcode;
   }
   public void setProductCode(int newproductcode)
   {
       Productcode = newproductcode;
   }


   /*method to set and get the quantity   for the messages*/
   public int getquantity()
   {
       return quantity;
   }

   public void setquantity(int newquantity)
   {
     quantity = newquantity;
   }

   /*method to set and get the Timestamp   for the messages*/
   public int getTimestamp ()
   {
       return Timestamp;
   }
   public void setTimestamp(int newTimestamp)
   {
       Timestamp = newTimestamp;
   }

   /*method to set and get the UOM   for the messages*/
   public byte[] getUOM()
   {
       return UOM;
   }

   public void setUOM(byte[] newUOM)
   {
       UOM = newUOM;
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the instruction message consists of 4 fields, you could create an Instruction class to encapsulate them. Then, for the queue you could use a list, and populate it with Instructions. For example, instantiate

```
LinkedList<Instruction> queue = new LinkedList<Instruction>();
```

You could then use queue.getFirst() and queue.addLast(...) to manipulate the queue's contents.

Comment: Thank you...I have created a class for instruction message and declared the fields in it ..how can i write  A METHOD IN INSTRUCTION QUEUE CLASS,should it include all the fields above to do that...

Comment: I have created a method for adding messages on queue..but when I use the queue.add()..Error is thown..can u pls help me

Comment: can i use LinkedList<Instructionmessage> queue = new LinkedList<Instructionmessage>();

Comment: Can you share the error message? You can use LinkedList to achieve this request.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO java class with all your variables. The create getters and setters for all variables. This will help you to set and get data using the methods.

Now create a Queue object in your main class and add(Object) method to add it in the queue.

```
Queue<String> sampleQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
sampleQueue.add("Joseph");
sampleQueue.add("Madhonna");
```

**Note:** Queue is an interface, so you cannot instantiate the object.

Possible exceptions can be thrown when you use this method. Refer this link for more details [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add%28E%29)

1. IllegalStateException - if the element cannot be added at this time
   due to capacity restrictions List item
2. ClassCastException - if the class of 
   the specified element prevents it from being added to this queue
3. NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this
   queue does not permit null elements
4. IllegalArgumentException - if some property of this element prevents it from being added to this queue

Comment: Can i use like this:LinkedList<Instructionmessage> queue = new LinkedList<Instructionmessage>();

Comment: Yes you can use LinkedList and add your objects. It will work fine. Use .add(object) or add(position, object) to add components. Please note that if you are using add(position, object) then be cautious to maintain the order of a queue. Check this link for more details about LinkedList http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html